# Como configurar a validação do ASP.NET MVC para aceitar datas pt-BR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, jquery-validate, annotation, globalização

Não consigo acertar a formatação da datas em meus formulários. Testei vários casos, todos usando a mesma view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

**Caso 1: Limpo e cru**

```
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

Resultado:
Aceita tudo, não faz validação alguma. E traz a data completa, inclusive nas views onde usei `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)`. Eu queria a abreviada pt-BR.

**Caso 2: Usando Annotation DataType**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

Resultado:
Melhorou, agora já formata a data (inclusive nas views que usei `DisplayFor()`), mas numa view com dados ela não as mostra e sim `dd/mm/aaaa`. Eu preencho com uma data qualquer, digitando ou selecionando no datapicker e ele aceita e sobrescreve a data salva.

**Caso 3: Usando DataType e DisplayFormat**

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data deste lançamento.")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }
```

Resultado:
Visualmente perfeito. Nas views que usei `DisplayFor()` ficou como queria e quando abro uma view com `EditorFor()` o campo exibe a data resumida, formatada e com o datapicker. Mas quando você altera a data a validação não aceita de forma alguma a data informada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quebrei cabeça dois dias procurando uma solução, estou usando o Globalization do NuGet com o culture configurado no `Web.config` e gostaria de fazer isso da forma mais acadêmica possível (isto é, direto na model ou no máximo passando algum atributo para o componente na view, evitando ao máximo mudar o Javascript padrão existente).

Comment: Você adicionou o jQuery-Validate-Globalize e o Globalize na sua solução?

Comment: Eu não tinha adicionado o jQuery-Validate-Globalize. Adicionei e corrigiu o `EditorFor()`. Mas nas views que uso `DisplayFor()` a data aparece `2015-07-14`.

Comment: Sim, é verdade. Gostaria que eu complemente isso como resposta?

Comment: Sim, por favor. E obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou adicionar o [jQuery.Validation.Globalize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Globalize/) no seu projeto e fazer referência a ele no `BundleConfig`.

Isto possivelmente vai trazer um problema extra: Seus `DateTime` irão aparecer como `YYYY-MM-DD`. Isto porque o `DisplayTemplate` (usando `@Html.DisplayFor()`) usa o que está no atributo `DisplayFormat`, então temos que sobrescrever este comportamento.

## Passo 1: Crie o diretório `DisplayTemplates`

Ele fica dentro de `~/Views/Shared`.

## Passo 2: Crie o template de `DateTime`

Dentro deste diretório, crie uma *View* chamada `DateTime.cshtml` com o seguinte:

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Convert.ToDateTime(Model).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
}
```