# Mudar formato de exibição de data na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte campo que me retorna a data da seguinte forma: 09/17/2018 11:52 AM

Como colocar ele dentro do padrão pt-br. Já tentei colocar o `.ToString("dd/MM//yyyy")` no `model.dtProtoclo` mas não funcionou.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dtprotocolo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dtprotocolo, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dtprotocolo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Não precisei detalhar tando, só o comentário a baixo solucionou meu problema

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como configurar a validação do ASP.NET MVC para aceitar datas pt-BR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87796/como-configurar-a-valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-asp-net-mvc-para-aceitar-datas-pt-br)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua ViewModel, adicione um `DataAnnotation` para o campo `DateTime`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Dtprotocolo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Coloquei esse código lá, fui fazer um add-migration nele não causou impacto algum. É isso mesmo? P.S. Coloquei no model de protocolo

Comment: Igonre, só adicionando o código do display format resolveu meu problema.

Obrigado